# Is this the full source code for ServiceKnownTypeAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

I want to see the source code for the `ServiceKnownType` attribute, as I am wondering about trying to write something that simulates a generic version of it. I'd like to start with the actual source code, and modify it.

I had a look at the .NET source code repository, and found [this link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/ServiceKnownTypeAttribute.cs), but the code there is very sparse, and doesn't look like it includes the implementation of the attribute. See below for the code.

I tried using a decompiler, but the resulting code looked basically the same. I don't understand how this attribute works without any code!

Anyone know where I can find the actual source, assuming it's been published of course.

Here is the source code from that link...

```
namespace System.ServiceModel
{
    [AttributeUsage(ServiceModelAttributeTargets.ServiceContract | ServiceModelAttributeTargets.OperationContract, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public sealed class ServiceKnownTypeAttribute : Attribute
    {
        Type declaringType;
        string methodName;
        Type type;

        private ServiceKnownTypeAttribute()
        {
            // Disallow default constructor
        }

        public ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(Type type)
        {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(string methodName)
        {
            this.methodName = methodName;
        }

        public ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(string methodName, Type declaringType)
        {
            this.methodName = methodName;
            this.declaringType = declaringType;
        }

        public Type DeclaringType
        {
            get { return declaringType; }
        }

        public string MethodName
        {
            get { return methodName; }
        }

        public Type Type
        {
            get { return type; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks pretty complete. Like most attributes it just associates some values (many have no values) along with the semantics of the attribute itself, so code reflecting on the members, types and/or assemblies the attribute is attached to can detect the presence of attributes they care about, and read any properties of the attribute if they want.

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting more code than that! So, if that's all there is, then I'm a bit stuck. As a variation of my original thought, suppose I want to write an attribute that is the equivalent of passing a method name to `ServiceKnownType` - how would I do that? I would want to specify the specific types in the attribute code, rather than passing a method. Thanks

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Attributes do not contain code, they are basically flags. There is always *external something* that knows to look for existence/absence of these flags and change its behaviour accordingly. E.g. the P/Invoke marshaller knows to look for the e.g. the `MarshalAs` attribute, this lookup is hardcoded in its code. So it never makes sense to introduce attributes to create logic if you also don't provide the *external something* that will be looking for that attribute type.

Comment: @Jon OK, thanks for the explanation. Looks like I'm getting in deeper than I understand! So if I wanted to write an attribute like `ServiceKnownType` but that returned a set of specific types, much like using the overload that allows you to specify a method that returns a collection of types, how would I do that? If I could do that, I would be able to make a start. Thanks again

Comment: How do you intend to use the attribute?

Comment: @Jon I have a set of types that I want to make known to a service call. I am currently using the overload of the attribute that allows you to specify a method that returns a collection of types. As my types are generic, I need to write a new method for each generic type. I was hoping to see if I could mimic a generic attribute by (say) passing the generic type as a string parameter. I wanted to start off with an attribute that just returned the types bound to a specific type, so I could see how it works, then try to make it more flexible. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Writing a custom attribute for an *existing* external thing to see only makes sense if you inherit from an attribute type the external thing is coded to recognize, and only in a way that keeps the attribute's data compatible with what the external thing is already prepared to see. Otherwise, while you can create an attribute that holds a collection of types, you cannot make any external thing to use it.

Comment: You would need to change the code that reads the attribute, rather than the attribute, in afraid.

Comment: @Jon Thanks to both of you. Looks like I'm trying to be too clever here. Guess I'll have to stick with the methods until they get around to implementing generic attributes.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you posted real source code of ServiceKnownTypeAttribute class. Attribute just describe entity and it does not contain any logic.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to have a look at the [Mono implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/0bcbe39b148bb498742fc68416f8293ccd350fb6/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ServiceKnownTypeAttribute.cs)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried using that code, but it failed miserably. I copied it into a new attribute `MyServiceKnownType` and changed the usage, but I got the same `SerializationException` as if I hadn't added the attribute at all. Any idea what went wrong? I copied the code verbatim.